# How to redirect route with data in javascript and laravel

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel

I wrote a `login.js` file in react and laravel .
What I want is , I send data to controller by using some `ajax request` and getting data back. 
I have a blade which accepts that data. 
Now I want to redirect `login.js` file to that blade file. 
How can I define the route inside javascript file ?
How can I redirect to blade file with data using js?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a javascript global variable inside blade file that contains script tag of loginjs and assign that variable with route. like this
     var route = "{{ route('link') }}";
     
after that code you can use the variable inside loginjs